# How can I listen for a result of socket.on in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a standard socket.io function like this :

```
function listen() {
    socket.on("event", function (data) {

        //return data ????

    });
}
```

I want to get the result of this function in another external function like this :

```
App.listen(function(data) {
    //getting the result of listen() when a event is trigerred
});
```

How should I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, it helped me to build my own solution.

Here is what I did :

```
App.on = function(callback) {
    App.socket.on(this.reference, callback);
}
```

And I call it like a simple listener :

```
App.on(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Simply pass a callback function from App.on, pass this function to socket.on, and do whatever you want in this function from App.on

Answer (score 0):

Like other events `socket.on` doesn't work like that. You can only capture the arguments, and not the return value.

```
App.value = null;
App.set_value = function(value){
    this.value = value
};

function listen() {
    socket.on("event", function (data) {

        App.value = data;
        //or
        App.set_value(data);
        //Last two calls will work
        //return data ???? will not work

    });
}
```

Alternatively you can do this.

```
function listen(App) {
    socket.on("event", function (data) {

        App.value = data;

        //or
        App.set_value(data);
        //Last two calls will work
        //return data ???? will not work

    });
}

listen(App)
```

If you need to continue a callback chain of events, or asynchronous operations then you can do this.

```
App.do_something = function(data, func){
    AsyncFunction(data, func);
};
function listen() {
    socket.on("event", function (data) {

        App.do_something(data, function(data){
            //Using async data.
        });

    });
}

listen(App);
```

If you are using Express(or some other framework) there might be other alternative ways to accomplish this.